# Misubishi MX component v4.0 not work in Thread

Tags: c#

I use MX component to connect and read from FX5u PLC.

And i want use thread in C#.But i get a exception "System.AccessViolationException: The exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to read or write protected memory. ".

Not necessarily when it happens.I think is Thread to cause.
Someone can supply better solution?

Maybe happend at "ActUtlType1.ReadDeviceBlock("D0", 1, out A)" or    ActUtlType1.ReadDeviceBlock("D1", 1, out B); or             ActUtlType1.ReadDeviceBlock("D0", 1, out A); or ActUtlType1.ReadDeviceBlock("D2", 1, out C);

Creat thread

```
private void From_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                PLCConnect[i] = new System.Threading.Thread(this.PLCControl);
                PLCConnect[i].IsBackground = true;
                if (PLCConnect[i].ThreadState != System.Threading.ThreadState.Running)
                {
                    PLCConnect[i].SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                    PLCConnect[i].Start(i + 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

```
private  void PLCControl(object plc)
{
    PLCNumber = Convert.ToInt16(plc);
    ActUtlTypeLib.ActUtlType ActUtlType1 = null;
    ActUtlType1 = new ActUtlTypeLib.ActUtlType();
    ActUtlType1.ActLogicalStationNumber=PLCNumber;
    iReturnCode = ActUtlType1.Open();
    if (iReturnCode == 0)
        {
            ActUtlType1.ReadDeviceBlock("D0", 1, out A); 
            ActUtlType1.ReadDeviceBlock("D1", 1, out B);
            ActUtlType1.ReadDeviceBlock("D2", 1, out C);

        }
   ActUtlType1.close();
   thread.sleep(500);
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you post the full exception message please, not just part of it.

Comment: But overall I would suggest using task-based asynchronous programming rather than threads. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. I will try.